# How to configure clang to use arm-none-eabi linker

Tags: compilation, embedded, clang, llvm-clang, cortex-m

I am trying to configure the last version of clang (6.0) to use the arm-none-eabi linker instead of the ld.lld but clang is always ignoring everything and keep asking for the ld.lld one. I am trying to build for cortex-m3 (lpx1769 board). How do I force clang to use the linker I want.

-fuse-ld=ld is also not working, so does clang no longer allow the use of any other linker?

Comment: make your own makefile and call the tools individually clang, opt, llc, ld.  llc can make an object (directly?) now so you dont need to call as anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am configuring and building a benchmark suite and I want to avoid any hacky solutions. I finally found how to do it using the flag: -fuse-ld=path/to/linker-to-be-used

Comment: sorry that you think using makefiles and available tools is hacky.  what you will find over time with llvm/clang is that these command line options come and go.  once you find one obscure one, they change it...so I guess that goes to your definition of hacky...

Comment: Actually you are right! This is indeed the case for llvm/clang. I will consider your solution for the long term! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to use the flag:

-fuse-ld=path/to/linker-to-be-used

Remember that if you passing this flag to clang it will cause a warning that clang will not use this flag (only the linker stage will do). Thus if you compiling with -Werror, the warning will be turned into an error.

Moreover, because you are cross-compiling probably you will need to let the linker know where to find the target-specific libraries needed using the -L option. See this for more info:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html